# SceneKit - Unbounded Memory Growth cause by childNode lookup

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I have an application that performs manipulations to `SCNNode`s in a loop - the application's memory goes to 2GB and crashes. My actual loop is very involved - it includes updating the `simdWorldTransform` of nodes, as well as removing and adding nodes.

To simplify it to the point where I can ask this question, I did a simple example where on the press of a button, it runs very simple actions like retrieving the child of an SCNNode - it still reaches 2GB and crashes.

The function:

```
func memoryLeakDetect() {

        for i in 1..<2001 {
            if i % 10 == 0 {
                print("Iteration = \(i)")
            }
            simpleLoop()
        }
    }
```

The `simpleLoop()`:

```
func simpleLoop() {
        for i in 0..<10000 {

            let pickIndex     = 1
            let pickLabelComp = saLabelComponents[pickIndex]
            let pickSprite    = LabelCompUtils.extractSprite(from: pickLabelComp) //MARK: CAUSING MEMORY LEAK!!!!
            // let pickSprite = saSprites[pickIndex]

        }
    }
```

It seems that the culprit is the call to `extractSprite` - because if I remove that  by storing the references to the sprite in an array, the program no longer crashes. I am including the `extractSprite` method. I am completely dumbfounded as to why this is causing the unbounded memory growth. What is causing this explosion of memory? I am simply looking up a node? There should be no references kept behind the scenes once I exit an iteration?

```
class LabelCompUtils {

    static func extractSprite(from labelComponent: SCNNode) -> SCNNode {
        if let sprite: SCNNode = labelComponent.childNode(withName: "sprite", recursively: false) {
            return sprite
        } else {
            return SCNNode()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use autoreleasepool.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't help in my more involved example. It works with the simple loop example, but not with the more involved examples.

Comment: @ElTomato: That seems to have done the trick - I take my earlier comment back. Can you please elaborate on why this resolves the issue? I now put the autoreleasepool statement right at the beginning of my method and it worked. Earlier, I was putting it right before the beginning of a for loop and the memory was going rampant.

Comment: Apple gives three reasons where you might need to use autoreleasepool.  In your case, you are creating many temporary objects in a loop quickly.  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: @ElTomato Except I am not creating objects at all - I am just get a node's child. With autoreleasepool now, it is just taking longer for the app to get to 2GB - but it it still getting there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, you are creating pickIndex each time, and presumably some of the times you're creating a new SCNNode when the lookup doesn't match.  With 20 million iterations, even pickIndex, a simple Int, uses a fair amount of storage -- 8 bytes * 20 million = 160 million, or about 160MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else that is dealing with this situation and there seem to be many, the following steps resolved the issue.

1. `autoreleasepool`: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

As @ElTomato suggested, since the loop may potentially be creating temporary objects in a loop, the use of `autoreleasepool` is recommended. Per Apple's documentation: "You may use an autorelease pool block inside the loop to dispose of those objects before the next iteration. Using an autorelease pool block in the loop helps to reduce the maximum memory footprint of the application."

Example:

```
// add leaderLineNodes
        for leaderLine in createleaderLineNodes(labelComponent: labelComponent) {
            autoreleasepool {
                labelComponent.addChildNode(leaderLine)
            }
        }
```

2. Run the application you are developing in "release mode".

The performance in Xcode may not be the same as that of real world device performance. Points 2 and 3 heavily influenced my application with both the memory footprint and execution speed. I was very surprised initially when profiling the app in Instruments to find out that the memory used was much lower than earlier - turns out Instruments runs the app in Release mode.

`Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Info -> Build Configuration -> Release Mode`

3. Disable Logging

`Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics -> Logging`